# How can I fetch data from my Database using Room when the input query is only part of that data?

Tags: java, android, jquery, android-room, dao

I have the below code, in my DAO, as an attempt to create a "quick search" function for my softphone application:

```
// Retrieve the numbers matching the query (e.g. for dialer quick search)
    @Query("SELECT * FROM phone_numbers_table WHERE phone_number LIKE :phoneNumber")
    List<PhoneNumber> getMatchingNumbers(String phoneNumber);
```

While dialing a number, I want my app to fetch all contact numbers that have in them the currently typed out string (i.e. if I have typed "456", I want to fetch all numbers that have "456" in them). However, the above code returns only the number which exactly matches the input query.

How can I change my code to return what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have searched more thoroughly, this is the answer:

```
// Retrieve the numbers matching the query (e.g. for dialer quick search)
    @Query("SELECT * FROM phone_numbers_table WHERE phone_number LIKE '%' || :phoneNumber || '%'")
    List<PhoneNumber> getMatchingNumbers(String phoneNumber);
```